# how to create shared lib from objects or static lib

Tags: c, linux, makefile, static-libraries

I would like to get shared libs for dynamic linking.

I have object files and static files, but no shared lib files.

Can I convert somehow them to create shared lib?

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=gcc+create+a+.so&oq=gcc+create+a+.so&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30l4.1856207.1859089.0.1859635.16.13.0.3.3.1.278.2000.1j9j3.13.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.8XHwWhtObCg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=aec810c57fc5a1bf&biw=1439&bih=854), first, second, third hit... they all have correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html.

Basically, you create a shared library like this:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.1 file1.o file2.o file3.o ...
```

The generated file will be named `libfoo.so.1.0.1`. However, you have to make sure that the `*.o` files were created with the `-fPIC` flag for position independent code or it won't work.

Comment: This can solve my problem indeed, but I have new problem:
gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
Do you know what is it? I googled to this, but no solution is found.

Comment: @TamasFekete Uh, no, I don't. If you don't find the solution yourself, you should open a new question.